# AJAX form send twice, second time with the response of first as URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I need to send the form asynchronously. So I wrote some code.

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="generate_params">
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign_id" value="202">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="AJAX_BANNERS_GENERATE">
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Generate" form="generate_params">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#generate_params").submit(function (e) {
        generateBanners();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

function generateBanners() {
    var data = $("#generate_params").serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        success: function (url) {
            $('#banners_gen').html('');
            $('#banners_gen').append($('<img>', {src: url}));
        }
    });
}
```

But there is a problem. The request send 2 times and the second is with url... as response of the first request. This is the most strange behavior I've ever seen.

[image]

So I googled a bit. Some people say that I should do `$(this).unbind()` in the `submit()` handler. But I need to send the form in future without page reload. So I need to re-bind the handler. But it seems not correct for me. Is there another way to solve it? What is happening actually?

## UPDATE

Server-side code to handle the action

```
$userPath = 'user/banners/generated';
$directory = $USER_FILE_DIR . $userPath;

$bannerName = Banner::generateFromTemplate($directory);

echo $USER_URL_PATH . "/" . $userPath . "/" . $bannerName;

exit(0);
```

Comment: to avoid the bind/unbind think you can use 

    $("body").submit('#generate_params', function (e) { ...

Comment: Look at fiddler and see if the header has different HTTP Codes. This could be normal behavior by the server trying to authenticate the request.

Comment: @JonasGrumann The result is the same. I still need to unbind.

Comment: @Anon What do you mean after different HTTP codes? The first response is `200 OK`, so I believe that is the client-side (jQuery) issue. And other AJAX requests on this site are sent correctly (but they aren't sent by `form.submit`).

Comment: I mean, sometimes this behavior occurs for me and Ill look in fiddler and the first request is an HTTP 401, then the second is a 200. Looking deeper into the issue, its the browser testing the server for the correct auth type. Not sure if thats what is happening here.

Comment: I suspect that second `GET` request you're seeing is for the newly created `<img>` element. Probably an issue with the PHP that generates the banner; you're expecting it to return just a URL, and it's instead returning something else (a PHP array?). Can you post that code?

Comment: @Anon The response of the first request is correct, so the authentication works.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Well, actually it supposed to return an URL. And it does. I just placed `var_dump` for debug. Wow, I'm such an idiot: the second `GET` is really made by browser to get the `<img>` contents and the `var_dump` is placed into the `scr` attribute. Maybe I should sleep more, because the `GET` with an image URL I considered as incorrect. So post an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't need the form.

```
<p id="generate_params">    
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign_id" value="202">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="AJAX_BANNERS_GENERATE">
</p>
<input type="button" id="generate_params_button">

$("#generate_params_button").on('click', function () {
    generateBanners();
});
```

...

Comment: No one has said anything about JUST removing the form tags.

Comment: Ok, you also changed the selector and event type slightly when calling `generateBanners()`. That function is going to fail to act as it does currently without the form because that's how it gets the data for the AJAX call. The form isn't causing the problems here, anyway, so that's definitely not the answer.

Comment: You are rigth. The first row inside generateBanners() needs to be: var data = $("#generate_params > input").serializeArray();

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

`<input type="submit" value="Generate" form="generate_params">`

to

`<input type="button" value="Generate" form="generate_params">`

Comment: If it's not a submit button then it won't trigger the submit event of the form, and their code won't execute. This definitely isn't the answer.